# Integration over solid angle using Monte Carlo method

Tags: scattering-cross-section

I'm trying to compute the integration of a particle physics scattering cross section over a solid angle using a Monte Carlo method and struggling to start. I've computed the integral using a trapezium rule so I'm fine with making the function, but not sure how to repeat using random numbers.

Particularly, I've defined the function to integrate and multiplied it by sin(theta) (from the definition of the solid angle) so I'm guessing I just need to generate random numbers for theta and phi. However, since the function is independent of phi, and the range of the phi integral is between 0 and 2pi I'm thinking I don't need to generate random numbers for phi since the integral is trivial (will just be 2pi multiplied by the integral at each point). So just wondering if I need to edit the function I'm integrating to generate random numbers or make a new function to generate the random numbers for the integration? Any help or direction to good sources would be a great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that:

$$ d^2\Omega =\sin{\theta} d\theta d\phi  = d(\cos{\theta})d\phi $$

So you can generate points $(\cos{\theta}, \phi)$ on a uniform rectangle defined by:

$$ 0 \le \phi \lt 2\pi $$
$$ -1 \le \cos{\theta} \le 1 $$

Comment: ok great thanks for the help. Since the function I need to integrate is only dependent on theta, could I just multiply the function by sin(theta) and then generate random numbers for theta between 0 and pi? Also, which way would you recommend to integrate the function? Do I need to amend the function I need to integrate or make a separate function to insert the one I wish to integrate?